# Regular Expression Exact Keyword Exclusion

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

Hi guys I am looking for a regular expression which will not match any given string that is exactly equal to a few keywords I will determine manually.

The purpose is to edit my urlrewrite.xml which can accept regexps in following format

```
<rule>
     <from>^/location/([A-Z]+)/name/([A-Z]+)</from>
     <to>/login?name=$2&location=$1</to>
</rule>
```

For example I want to redirect everything after / which is not 'login' and 'signup' to another page. I am trying following ones but none satisfies my request.

```
^/(?!(login|signup).*
^/(?!(login|signup)[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Because I want it to match only if input is exactly 'login' or 'signup' however, it declines '*loginblabla*', too.

Any solutions are highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you just use the [end of string anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`?

Comment: Don't put * at the start or the end of a regex, it's unnecessary and it makes processing a lot slower. Leaving it out has the exact same effect.

Comment: I don't understand what the regex needs to do.  Can you give some precise examples of what you want to match and not match?   Also, what language?

Comment: What about: *^/((!(l))|(l!(o))|(lo!(g))|(log!(i)|(logi!(n))|(login[a-zA-Z0-9]))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `$` anchor at the end of the lookahead:

```
^/(?!(login|signup)$)(.+)
```

Now anything that isn't *exactly* `login` or `signup` will be captured in group `$1`.

Comment: +1 That would be more logical then mine, was a left over brainfart from another regex excursion yesterday.

Comment: It will be captured in $2. $1 will capture login or signup.

Comment: Right. I forgot to add the `?:` to make that first group non-capturing.

Comment: Thanks Alan. This one solved my problem: ^/(login|signup)((/.*)?)$

Thanks to that one, I can forward /a/b/ schemes, too.